# Как перейти на следующий элемент под одинаковым классом bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, bs4

Паршу страничку в вк, дошел до местонахождения, и чтоб спарсить именно название города выставляется следующая картина(фото снизу), и тут мне надо спарсить второй labeled, вот мое решение

```
for item in items:
    place = item.find('div', class_='profile_info')
    if place:
        place = place.find('div', class_='clear_fix').nextSibling().find('div', class_='labeled').find('a').get_text()
    else:
        print('не указан')
```

но выдает ошибку

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Как исправить? Подскажите

[image: теги которые нужно спрасить]

Comment: `place.find('div', class_='clear_fix').find_next('div', class_='labeled')...` и так далее

Comment: А ошибка говорит о том, что один из ваших элементов не `Tag` а `ResultSet` фактически список